# Chrome extension button popup stuck open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Lately the popup bubble that shows when you click a chrome extension will randomly get stuck open, or will not open at all. Here's an example of it getting stuck open:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any pattern to it. It happens for all the different extensions, and I didn't add/remove/change anything (other than updating my browser) lately that might affect this.

Most of the time when I click an extension button, it will flash open and then minimize down to a small white bubble as above, and only after clicking it four or five times does it stay open.

Reinstalling Chrome hasn't helped, and I'm not really sure what else to do. I'm running Version 31.0.1650.63 on Mavericks. Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: I haven't come across such an issue. Maybe right-clicking on a stucked-open popup and clicking "Inspect element", then moving over to the "Console" tab would reveal some strange error...

Comment: http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines

Comment: It actually won't let me right click it, but when I manually go into the console, nothing strange shows up.

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your popup's HTML file? I had similar strange sizing issues without that.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. The popup is attached to the extension button, so I can't view the source the way I could if it was in a web page.