# Chrome extension disable page action popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to use [pageAction.onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#event-onClicked), The document says the event will not fire if there is a popup:

> Fired when a page action icon is clicked. This event will not fire if the page action has a popup.

So I am looking for a way to disable the popup. Right now I tried something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.pageAction.setPopup({
    tabId: tabs[0].id, popup: ''
  });
});
```

I didn't specify default_pop in `manifest.json`.

But this doesn't disable the popup, any advice?

Related: [Chrome extension button popup stuck open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996655/chrome-extension-button-popup-stuck-open)

Comment: Don't use default_popup in manifest.json

Comment: Thanks, updated my question, I didn't have `default_popup`.

Comment: I guess it wants you to remove popups from all tab ids. The use case of onClicked is different so you shouldn't have used any setPopup in the first place.